# What is difference between socket.on and io.on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Server side code:

```
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log('New WEBSocket Connection')

 
    socket.emit('message',"welcome")
    socket.broadcast.emit('message',"A new user joined")

    socket.on('textMessage',(message,callback)=>{

        const filter = new Filter();
        if(filter.isProfane(message)){
            return callback('Mind your languezz')
        }

        io.emit('message',message)
        callback()
    })
}
```

Client side code:

```
socket.emit('textMessage',message,(error)=>{
        if(error){
            return console.log(error)

        }
        console.log("Message Delivered")
    })
```

My doubt is, on client side code, what if I used io.on instead of socket.on?
`socket.on('textMessage',(message,callback)=>{............`instead I did it like this:
`io.on('textMessage',(message,callback)=>{.............`

Comment: My assumption is socket.on listens for data from it's own server whereas io.on will listen for all. So it should work right? Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between io.on and socket.on in Socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703546/difference-between-io-on-and-socket-on-in-socket-io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`io.on` listens to the server events. `connection` is an event on the server, when a socket is connected. And when that socket is connected, the callback function inside that is run.

`socket.on` listens to events on **that connected socket**.   `socket.on('textMessage'` asks to do something when `textMessage` event is emitted on the socket, which you do from your client using `socket.emit('textMessage'`